# SQL: How can I take only the first match for each in an inner join?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have these tables:

**USER**

userId | partnerCode

**PARTNER**

partnerId | readableName | ... | partnerCode | ...

And we want:

```
select USER.userId, PARTNER.readableName
from USER
inner join PARTNER
on PARTNER.partnerCode = USER.partnerCode
where USER.userId = <someUser>;
```

However, for each userId:partnerCode pair in USER, there can be many PARTNER entries that have that partnerCode. We only care about taking the first PARTNER.readableName that we find in the join'd table (and order doesn't matter).

How can I query thusly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: DO you have a userCode column in table USER ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Oops! Yes, that should read USER.partnerCode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this using the ANSI standard window function `row_number()`:

```
select u.userId, p.readableName
from USER u inner join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.partnerCode order by p.partnerCode) as seqnum
      from PARTNER p
     ) p
     on p.partnerCode =  u.userCode and seqnum = 1
where u.userId = <someUser>;
```

Given the structure of your query, it would often be faster to use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.userId,
       (select p.readableName
        from PARTNER p
        where p.partnerCode =  u.userCode 
        fetch first 1 row only  -- order doesn't matter, so there is no order by
      ) as readableName
from USER u
where u.userId = <someUser>;
```

For optimal performance, you want indexes on `user(userId)` and `partner(partnerCode, readableName)`.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you suggest the standard window function row_number() and not the standard window function first_value()?  first_values seems to make more sense to me in this case.

Comment: @Hogan . . . `row_number()` comes to mind first.  I have a partial mental block against `first_value()`, simply because it is not also an aggregation function.

Comment: You know what I'm going to say... row_number() is also not an aggregation function.  :D

Comment: @Hogan . . . But it *cannot* be, due to its definition.  Technically, it is a ranking function.  `First_value()` would just be very convenient as an aggregation function.